How do I customize the ConversionService used by JdbcClient?
I'm trying to read a record with JdbcClient.
One column should be converted to a custom type.
From the documentation and multiple web searches I understand I should create and register a Converter to accomplish this.
Unfortunately I always and up with the same org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.example.demo.DemoApplication$PersonName] exception.
How do I customize the ConversionService used by JdbcClient?
I know I can work around this problem by using a RowMapper but I'm trying to avoid it.
This is the code I'm running with java 17 and spring boot 3.3.0.
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*** DemoApplication.main");
        SpringApplication.run(new Class[]{
                        MyWebConfiguration.class,
                        MyOtherConfiguration.class,
                        DemoApplication.class
                },
                args);
    }

    private final JdbcClient jdbcClient;

    public DemoApplication(JdbcClient jdbcClient) {
        System.out.println("*** DemoApplication.DemoApplication");
        this.jdbcClient = jdbcClient;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        final List<Person> list = jdbcClient.sql("select 'John;Doe' as \"name\" from dual")
                .query(Person.class)
                .list();
        System.out.println("list = " + list);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class MyWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        private final StringToPersonNameConverter stringToPersonNameConverter;

        public MyWebConfiguration(StringToPersonNameConverter stringToPersonNameConverter) {
            System.out.println("*** MyWebConfiguration.MyWebConfiguration");
            this.stringToPersonNameConverter = stringToPersonNameConverter;
        }

        @Override
        public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
            registry.addConverter(stringToPersonNameConverter);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class MyOtherConfiguration {
        private final ConfigurableEnvironment environment;
        private final ConverterRegistry converterRegistry;
        private final GenericConversionService conversionService;
        private final StringToPersonNameConverter stringToPersonNameConverter;

        public MyOtherConfiguration(
                ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
                ConverterRegistry converterRegistry,
                GenericConversionService conversionService,
                StringToPersonNameConverter stringToPersonNameConverter) {
            System.out.println("*** MyOtherConfiguration.MyOtherConfiguration");
            this.environment = environment;
            this.converterRegistry = converterRegistry;
            this.conversionService = conversionService;
            this.stringToPersonNameConverter = stringToPersonNameConverter;
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void addCustomConverters() {
            environment.getConversionService().addConverter(stringToPersonNameConverter);
            converterRegistry.addConverter(stringToPersonNameConverter);
            conversionService.addConverter(stringToPersonNameConverter);
        }
    }

    @Component
    @ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
    public static class StringToPersonNameConverter implements Converter<String, PersonName> {
        public StringToPersonNameConverter() {
            System.out.println("*** StringToPersonNameConverter.StringToPersonNameConverter");
        }

        @Override
        public PersonName convert(String source) {
            if (source.contains(";")) {
                String[] parts = source.split(";", 2);
                return new PersonName(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
            return new PersonName(source, "?");
        }
    }

    public record Person(PersonName name) {
    }

    public record PersonName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    }

}

The output looks like this:
2024-06-21T16:28:14.535+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.11 with PID 23272 (C:\Workspace\demo\build\classes\java\main started by kristof in C:\Workspace\demo)
2024-06-21T16:28:14.540+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
*** StringToPersonNameConverter.StringToPersonNameConverter
2024-06-21T16:28:15.122+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-06-21T16:28:15.128+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-06-21T16:28:15.128+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.24]
2024-06-21T16:28:15.161+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-06-21T16:28:15.161+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 590 ms
*** MyWebConfiguration.MyWebConfiguration
*** MyOtherConfiguration.MyOtherConfiguration
*** DemoApplication.DemoApplication
2024-06-21T16:28:15.718+02:00  WARN 23272 --- [demo] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Invocation of init method failed
2024-06-21T16:28:15.720+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-06-21T16:28:15.727+02:00  INFO 23272 --- [demo] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-06-21T16:28:15.737+02:00 ERROR 23272 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Invocation of init method failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:222) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1780) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:25) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.example.demo.DemoApplication$PersonName]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:294) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:185) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService.convert(ConversionService.java:92) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SimplePropertyRowMapper.mapRow(SimplePropertyRowMapper.java:141) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:733) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:754) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:767) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:825) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.DefaultJdbcClient$DefaultStatementSpec$IndexedParamMappedQuerySpec.list(DefaultJdbcClient.java:346) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.init(DemoApplication.java:44) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMethod.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:401) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-beans-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 17 common frames omitted


Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/73849450/1776495 - could you try inheriting a configuration from AbstractJdbcConfiguration and override jdbcCustomConversions()?

This "AbstractJdbcConfiguration" would probably work for "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc", but I don't use it. The JdbcClient isn't using the same converters.

I've found one way to add a converter to the ConversionService used by JdbcClient. It isn't recommended.
    @Configuration
    public static class MyOtherConfiguration {
        private final StringToPersonNameConverter stringToPersonNameConverter;

        public MyOtherConfiguration(StringToPersonNameConverter stringToPersonNameConverter) {
            this.stringToPersonNameConverter = stringToPersonNameConverter;
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void addCustomConverters() {
            // NOT recommended
            ((DefaultConversionService) DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance()).addConverter(stringToPersonNameConverter);
        }
    }

I've also found a way to avoid writing a full-blown custom RowMapper. Apparently a SimplePropertyRowMapper with a custom ConversionService is enough.
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SimplePropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*** DemoApplication.main");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    private final JdbcClient jdbcClient;
    private final RowMapper<Person> personRowMapper;

    public DemoApplication(JdbcClient jdbcClient, RowMapper<Person> personRowMapper) {
        System.out.println("*** DemoApplication.DemoApplication");
        this.jdbcClient = jdbcClient;
        this.personRowMapper = personRowMapper;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        final List<Person> list = jdbcClient.sql("select 'John;Doe' as \"name\" from dual")
                .query(personRowMapper)
                .list();
        System.out.println("list = " + list);
    }

    @Component
    public static class StringToPersonNameConverter implements Converter<String, PersonName> {
        public StringToPersonNameConverter() {
            System.out.println("*** StringToPersonNameConverter.StringToPersonNameConverter");
        }

        @Override
        public PersonName convert(String source) {
            if (source.contains(";")) {
                String[] parts = source.split(";", 2);
                return new PersonName(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
            return new PersonName(source, "?");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public static RowMapper<Person> personRowMapper(ConversionService myConversionService) {
        System.out.println("*** DemoApplication.personRowMapper");
        return new SimplePropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class, myConversionService);
    }

    @Bean
    public static ConversionService myConversionService(Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
        final GenericConversionService conversionService = new GenericConversionService();
        DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(conversionService);
        for (Converter<?, ?> converter : converters) {
            conversionService.addConverter(converter);
        }
        return conversionService;
    }

    public record Person(PersonName name) {
    }

    public record PersonName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    }

}

